# "Congratulate for" vs. "congratulate on"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

Which is correct?

> I congratulated him **for** coming first in the race.
>
> I congratulated him **on** coming first in the race.

Answer (score 35):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/congratulate?q=congratulate) the verb **congratulate** collocates with both prepositions, but the meaning is slightly different.

When you *congratulate someone **on** something* you give them your good wishes because something special or pleasant has happened to them, e.g. "I'd like to congratulate you on your marriage".

When you *congratulate someone **for** something* you praise them for an achievement, e.g. "I'd like to congratulate the staff for their good job".

According to Google [NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=congratulate+you+on%2Ccongratulate+you+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) *congratulate on* is a lot more frequent than *congratulate for*, but the latter is used nevertheless.

To answer your question, both sound natural to me.

Comment: Even to me "congratulate for" sounds more natural (and I also hear people speaking it). But I couldn't find a trusted source which gave an example of "congratulate for".

Comment: @HiAll: Did you follow the links in my answer? That's why they are there, to provide sources.

Comment: In this question I think for is more apt than on as we are appreciating him for his achievement for coming first in the race.

Comment: @Sudhir: Nah. You normally offer congratulations ***on** an achievement*, but ***for** acting in a certain way*. But I don't think that can be called a difference in *meaning* - it's more an idiomatic tendency of *grammar*.

Comment: I couldn't agree with Irene more on that. Good answer Irene! Congratulations for your answer. And congratulations on your job. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for Google [NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=congratulate+you+on%2Ccongratulate+you+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) link!

Answer (score 5):

In common mistakes in English by T.j.Fitikides (Longman) is written congratulate on not for and didn't say anything why **on** not **for**. 
Ex: Don't say: I congratulate you for your success.
Say: I congratulate you on your success.
(Common Mistakes in English)

Answer (score -2):

Both of the cases are correct, so you can use any expression you like.

Comment: They may be both correct but they have slightly different meanings, as mentioned in another answer.  So you shouldn't use any expression you like, you use the one that is appropriate.